# angular directive load after got variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive that loads data from service,
BUT
it loads the data with a variable he go from a controller that it was loaded as well from a service.

code: 
directive:

```
app.directive("posts", ['Posts', function(Posts) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',

    template: '' +
    '<div ng-repeat="post in posts"></div>',
    scope: {
        showLoading: '&',
        hideLoading: '&',
        spot: '@'
    },

    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }],

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         $scope.load = function () {
            Posts.loadPostsBySpot(scope.spot)
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('spotPageController', ['$scope', 'Spots', function ($scope, $Spots) {

    doit = function () {
        Spots.getSpot($)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.spotId = data.data;
                console.log($scope.spot);
            }).error(function (data) {
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
 }]);
```

html inside

```
<posts spot="{{spotId}}" showLoading="showLoading()" hideLoading="hideLoading()"></posts>
```

but when the directive is loaded the "spot" is not yet set,
so how do I make the directive load only after the spot is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

```
<posts ng-if="spotId" spot="{{spotId}}" showLoading="showLoading()" hideLoading="hideLoading()"></posts>
```

This element will be rendered only after the `spotId` is initialized. Therefore, your directive will not be called before that.

If you want to encapsulate this behavior in directive, you should watch for changes of the scopeId. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fracz/U3pVM/11823/).

Comment: Great! one question, can I place an "if(spotId)" inside the link function and load only when it is set other wise show "no posts"

Comment: You can wait for a value with [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method of the `$scope`. For "no posts" message, I would add `<div ng-hide="posts.length">No posts</div>` to the directive template.

Comment: thanks @Wojciech Frącz, read it, can you please add a tiny example?